# Question regarding mergesort's merge algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

Let's suppose we have two sorted arrays, A and B, consisting of n elements. I dont understand why the time needed to merge these 2 is "n+n". In order to merge them we need to compare 2n-1 elements. For example, in the two following arrays

```
A = [3, 5, 7, 9] and B = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

We will start merging them into a single one, by comparing the elements in the known way. However when we finally compare 8 with 9. Now, this will be our 2n-1=8-1=7th comparison and 8 will be inserted into the new array.

After this the 9 will be inserted without another comparison. So I guess my question is, since there are 2n-1 comparisons, why do we say that this merging takes 2n time? Im not saying O(n), im saying T(n)=2n, an exact time function.

Its probably a detail that im missing here so I would be very grateful if someone could provide some insight. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do "we" say it will take `2n` time?  It actually takes anywhere from `n` to `2n-1` comparisons.  However it is bounded above by `2n`, and for complexity analysis, that's good enough.

Comment: It's not just the number of comparisons, insertion takes time too.

Comment: A typical merge sort is not an in-place sort. Every element in A and B needs to be moved the output array. So there are always exactly `2n` moves. The number of comparisons is between `n` and `2n-1`. But whether a comparison takes more or less  time than a move depends on the constant factors for those two operations. The time is also affected by things like cache performance. Which is why *"an exact time function"* is not a thing. There are only rough estimates of time, where the difference between `2n` and `2n-1` is irrelevant for any reasonably large value of `n`.

Comment: You seem to consider that the time is "universally" said to be 2n. You'd better show us your reference, maybe there's an explanation such as "about 2n"...

Comment: Thanks for the answers.Yes, amount of comparisons varies, depending on the length of the arrays. I am talking about this particular problem and similar ones, with 2 sorted arrays of equal length. In this one, the comparisons needed are 2n-1, but in the lecture I watched the professor said that the merging (for this problem) will take 2n time, not 2n-1. As @user3386109 mentioned, there are 2n insertions into a new array that are needed to be done. I know that 2n and 2n-1 are the same for very large values of n. So perhaps in merge, we take into account the insertions and not the comparisons?

Comment: It's not so much that you're picking one or the other (insertions versus comparisons). Each of those operations is needed about the same number of times (2n), where each operation takes some amount of time (T). So the overall running is about 2nT. But that's just a rough estimate (since you need to estimate T), not an exact number.

Comment: Ok @user3386109, thanks. The idea I get so far from these concepts is that I shouldnt sweat it very much because they are just approximations. The true times needed are certainly different, even though not by a large margin.